# How do I convert string to dictionary?

Tags: json, python-3.x

I am trying to convert this string into a json object : -

```
coordinates = "{ lat: '55,7303650017903', lng: '12,3446636123658' }"
```

I tried using json.loads(), it didn't work for me. 
Is there a way I can achieve this?

Comment: string looks like javascript object

Comment: I was just about to comment as per @Chris Doyles comment -- this is not a python dictionary as your keys do not have quotes around them

Comment: The problem you have is that this string is neither a valid python dict nor valid json object.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the correction. 
But is there a way I can retrieve the value of a key? For example , the value of 'lat'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend using demjson python parser for achieving this , since the string is js object

```
import demjson
print(demjson.decode("{ lat: '55,7303650017903', lng: '12,3446636123658' }"))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is really useful

Comment: Note that other solutions do not need installing package

Answer (score 2):

Using regex to add quotes around the key and then use the `ast` module

**Ex:**

```
import re
import ast

coordinates = "{ lat: '55,7303650017903', lng: '12,3446636123658' }"
coordinates = re.sub(r"(\w+)(?=:)", r'"\1"', coordinates)
print(ast.literal_eval(coordinates))
```

**Output:**

```
{'lat': '55,7303650017903', 'lng': '12,3446636123658'}
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution would be to use a regular expression:

```py
import re

coordinates = "{ lat: '55,7303650017903', lng: '12,3446636123658' }"
pattern = r"{ lat: '(.*)', lng: '(.*)' }"
lat, lng = re.findall(pattern, coordinates)[0]
```

This solution does not require importing any additional packages beyond `re`. If you want then want a dictionary with those values:

```py
cords = { "lat": lat, "lng": lng }
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use json.loads:

```
import json

coordinates = '{ "lat": "55,7303650017903", "lng": "12,3446636123658" }'

datastore = json.loads(coordinates)

print(json.dumps(datastore))
```

You can try in an online repl: https://repl.it/languages/python3

Comment: This isnt a solution since your string is not the same as the string the OP has

Comment: Sure, like its been said need quotes on the keys. this is implicit.

Comment: yeah but this isnt a general solution. you have to assume the OP is getting this string from somewhere else and it could haev anything in it. If your answer is the OP should just implicitly change the string. you may as well say the OP can implicitly write it as s dict in the code

Comment: Ok, Chris! Got it! Thanks!